# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC : validate form before modal window

Tags: validation, jquery-ui, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC app, and I have a form with validations and submit button. I am displaying a jQuery UI Modal window on clicking submit. I want the validations to fire before showing the modal window.

It's displaying modal window without firing the validations. Please find my code below.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewUser", "Login"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div style="margin: auto; border-radius: 15px; border:solid; padding: 15px; width: 35%;">
        <table>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><span style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">@ViewBag.Result</span></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">Sign Up<br /><h1>Let's get started.</h1>Fill out the basic information below to set up your account.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PreferredName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</b><br />
                    Enter your preferred Name (First and Last)<br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PreferredName, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", size = "50", placeholder = "Preferred Name" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PreferredName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PersonalEmail, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</b><br />
                    Enter your contact details (only one is required)<br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PersonalEmail, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", size = "50", placeholder = "Email", type = "email" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonalEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryCode, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                                         new SelectListItem() {Text = "US (+1)", Value ="+1"},
                                         new SelectListItem() {Text = "IN (+91)", Value ="+91"}

                     }, null, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 120px;" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", style = "width: 310px;", placeholder = "Phone Number" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsTextORCallingOk, new { @class = "form-check-input" })&nbsp;This number can receive texts
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</b><br />
                    Enter your preferred username (min 3 characters)<br />
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", size = "50", placeholder = "Preferred Username" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</b><br />
                    Enter an account password<br />
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", size = "50", placeholder = "Password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })<br />
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off", size = "50", placeholder = "Confirm Password" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TimeZone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</b><br />
                    Select your locations timezone<br />
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TimeZone, new List<SelectListItem>
                       {
                                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "UTC - 08:00", Value ="UTC - 08:00", Selected = true}

                       }, null, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 400px;" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Currency, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</b><br />
                    Select your preferred currency<br />
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency, new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "USD - $", Value ="USD", Selected = true}

                    }, null, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 400px;" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Temperature, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })</b><br />
                    Select your preferred unit of temparature measurement<br />
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Temperature, new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                                         new SelectListItem() {Text = "Fahrenheit (F)", Value ="Fahrenheit", Selected = true},
                                         new SelectListItem() {Text = "Celcius (C)", Value="Celcius"}
                     }, null, new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 400px;" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:black; color: white; font-size: large;" type="button">Sign Up</button></td>
                <td align="right"><a href="/">Cancel</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="left">*&nbsp;Denotes a required field</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 35%;">
        <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr><td align="left">Have an account?&nbsp;<a href="#">Sign In</a></td><td align="right">Have an Join Code?&nbsp;<a href="#">Use Join Code</a></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Terms of Use</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#">Contact Support</a></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}

<div id="dialog-form" style="margin: auto; border-radius: 15px; border:solid; padding: 15px; width: 40%;">
    <table>
        <tr><td><h1>Terms of Use</h1></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                By creating an account, I accept Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui soluta natus non recusandae repellendus et ducimus ipsa. Ea dolorem cumque et facilis quidem aut corporis iusto aut quis architecto.
                Aut quia deserunt ea veritatis laborum ut nostrum ratione et sint sequi aut totam reprehenderit. Ut neque sapiente ab voluptatem quaerat cum tempore enim est quia eaque. Et earum magni ut quas internos non voluptas quia 33 animi labore non doloremque reprehenderit in ipsam unde. In ipsa cupiditate non nesciunt voluptatem ut accusamus corrupti.
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="margin: auto; border-radius: 15px; border:solid; padding: 15px; overflow:scroll; height:200px;">
                    <h3>1.Overview</h3>Welcome to Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Qui soluta natus non recusandae repellendus et ducimus ipsa. Ea dolorem cumque et facilis quidem aut corporis iusto aut quis architecto.
                    Aut quia deserunt ea veritatis laborum ut nostrum ratione et sint sequi aut totam reprehenderit. Ut neque sapiente ab voluptatem quaerat cum tempore enim est quia eaque. Et earum magni ut quas internos non voluptas quia 33 animi labore non doloremque reprehenderit in ipsam unde. In ipsa cupiditate non nesciunt voluptatem ut accusamus corrupti.
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr><td><input id="chkTerms" type="checkbox" />&nbsp;I have read and understood the terms...</td></tr>
        @*<tr><td align="left"><input type="button" value="Agree & Continue" disabled /></td><td align="right"><a href="#">Cancel</a></td></tr>*@
    </table>
</div>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    var dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 650,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Agree & Continue": submitParentForm,
                Cancel: function () {
                    dialog.dialog("close");
                }
            },
            close: function () {
            }
        });

        $("#btnSignUp").button().on("click", function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");
        });
```

Comment: Hi @Mohan Raju , can you show your view code?

Answer (score 0):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewUser", "Login"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div style="margin: auto; border-radius: 15px; border:solid; padding: 15px; width: 35%;">
        //change `table` to `form` and add Id
         <form id="ssss">
             ......
              
             <td align="left"><button id="btnSignUp" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color:black; color: white; font-size: large;" type="button">Sign Up</button></td>
             ......
         </form>
    </div>
    ......

@section Scripts
{

        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script>
              var dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 650,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Agree & Continue": submitParentForm,
                    Cancel: function () {
                        dialog.dialog("close");
                    }
                },
                close: function () {
                }
              });


               
             $("#btnSignUp").click(function(){
                var validator = $("#ssss").validate();
                var flag = validator.form();
                if(flag){
                   dialog.dialog("open");
                }
              });
            

             function submitParentForm(){}       
        </script>
 }
```

Comment: I have already added those. It's still showing the popup on click instead of validating the form.

Comment: can you provide your view code?

Comment: Updated with view.

Comment: Hi @MohanRaju ,I have updated my answer,You can make some changes to your code according to my answer。